# ContextRefreshedEvent is not being catched

Tags: spring-boot, applicationcontext

I am setting up a spring boot application with postgres database
The postgres server is up and does not have much to do with the issue.

Following are my classes:

> ```
> package com.example.demo.service.config;
>
> import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
> import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
> import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
> import org.springframework.context.event.ContextStartedEvent;
>
> @SpringBootApplication 
> public class ServiceConfiguration {
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>       SpringApplication.run(ServiceConfiguration.class, args);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> package com.example.demo.service.config;
>
> import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
> import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
> import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
> import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
>
> @Configuration
> @EnableAutoConfiguration
> @EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.persistence"})
> @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.repositories"})
> @EnableTransactionManagement
> public class RepositoryConfiguration {
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> package com.example.demo.repositories;
>
> import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
>
> import com.example.demo.persistence.Product;
>
> @Component
> public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer>{
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> package com.example.demo.persistence;
>
> import javax.persistence.*;
> import java.math.BigDecimal;
>
> @Entity
> public class Product {
>     @Id   
>     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
>     @SequenceGenerator(name="product_id_sequence", sequenceName="product_id_sequence", allocationSize=1)
>     @Column(name="ID")
>     private Integer id;
>
>     @Version
>     private Integer version;
>
>     private String productId;
>     private String description;
>     private String imageUrl;
>     private BigDecimal price;
>
>     public String getDescription() {
>         return description;
>     }
>
>     public void setDescription(String description) {
>         this.description = description;
>     }
>
>     public Integer getVersion() {
>         return version;
>     }
>
>     public void setVersion(Integer version) {
>         this.version = version;
>     }
>
>     public Integer getId() {
>         return id;
>     }
>
>     public void setId(Integer id) {
>         this.id = id;
>     }
>
>     public String getProductId() {
>         return productId;
>     }
>
>     public void setProductId(String productId) {
>         this.productId = productId;
>     }
>
>     public String getImageUrl() {
>         return imageUrl;
>     }
>
>     public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
>         this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
>     }
>
>     public BigDecimal getPrice() {
>         return price;
>     }
>
>     public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
>         this.price = price;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> package com.example.demo.bootstrap;
>
> import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
> import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
> import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
>
> import com.example.demo.persistence.Product;
> import com.example.demo.repositories.ProductRepository;
>
> import java.math.BigDecimal;
>
> @Component
> public class ProductLoader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
>
>     private ProductRepository productRepository;
>
>     private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ProductLoader.class);
>
>     @Autowired
>     public void setProductRepository(ProductRepository productRepository) {
>         this.productRepository = productRepository;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
>
>       System.err.println("Flow never comes here !!");
>
>         Product shirt = new Product();
>         shirt.setDescription("Spring Framework Guru Shirt");
>         shirt.setPrice(new BigDecimal("18.95"));
>         shirt.setImageUrl("https://springframework.guru/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/spring_framework_guru_shirt-rf412049699c14ba5b68bb1c09182bfa2_8nax2_512.jpg");
>         shirt.setProductId("235268845711068308");
>         productRepository.save(shirt);
>
>         log.info("Saved Shirt - id: " + shirt.getId());
>
>         Product mug = new Product();
>         mug.setDescription("Spring Framework Guru Mug");
>         mug.setImageUrl("https://springframework.guru/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/spring_framework_guru_coffee_mug-r11e7694903c348e1a667dfd2f1474d95_x7j54_8byvr_512.jpg");
>         mug.setProductId("168639393495335947");
>         productRepository.save(mug);
>
>         log.info("Saved Mug - id:" + mug.getId());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> ---

The ProductLoader class is a component and implements ApplicationListener, still the flow never comes in onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) method.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Got the issue resolved.

Added following annotations to the ServiceConfiguration class
```

> ```
> @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.demo.bootstrap","com.example.demo.persistence"})
> @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {ProductRepository.class})
> @EntityScan(basePackageClasses=Product.class)
> public class ServiceConfiguration {
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>       SpringApplication.run(ServiceConfiguration.class, args);
>   }
> }
> ```